# Getting user C String input into exec() function in c

Tags: c, input, exec, fork, c-strings

Here is the general problem:
The program must `fork()` and `wait()` for the child to finish.
The child will `exec()` another program whose name is INPUT by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int status;
    char input[BUFSIZ];
    printf(">");
    scanf("%s",input);
    char *args[] = {"./lab1"};
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
    execvp(args[0],args);
    }else if(pid<0){
        perror("Fork fail");
    }else{
        wait(&status);
        printf("My Child Information is: %d\n", pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is getting the user to input a program name to run (at the ">" prompt) and getting that input into execvp (or another exec() function if anyone has any ideas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hold off lambasting you for using `scanf("%s")` for now, though you should be aware it's really not [robust code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

Your basic task here is going to be taking a character array entered by the user and somehow turning that into an array of character pointers suitable for passing to `execvp`.

You can use `strtok` to tokenise the input string into tokens separated by spaces, and `malloc/realloc` to ensure you have enough elements in an array to store the strings.

Alternatively, since you already have a potential buffer overflow issue, it may be good enough to just use a fixed size array.

---

For example, the following program shows one way of doing this, it uses a fixed string `echo my hovercraft is full of eels` and tokenises it to be suitable for execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *myStrDup (char *str) {
    char *other = malloc (strlen (str) + 1);
    if (other != NULL)
        strcpy (other, str);
    return other;
}

int main (void) {
    char inBuf[] = "echo my hovercraft is full of eels";
    char *argv[100];
    int argc = 0;

    char *str = strtok (inBuf, " ");
    while (str != NULL) {
        argv[argc++] = myStrDup (str);
        str = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    argv[argc] = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf ("Arg #%d = '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    execvp (argv[0], argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Then it outputs the tokenised arguments and executes it:

```
Arg #0 = 'echo'
Arg #1 = 'my'
Arg #2 = 'hovercraft'
Arg #3 = 'is'
Arg #4 = 'full'
Arg #5 = 'of'
Arg #6 = 'eels'

my hovercraft is full of eels
```

Comment: This is for class, learning about fork and exec, thanks for your response, I am trying to keep this as simple as possible.